# Parallax Fixed Scroll is not working when using Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, parallax

I need to create a parallax scroll effect as below but it's not working as per the expectation.

When scrolling, I need to have a fixed section with contents and want to scroll only one section which is having the content.

When I use the script in Bootstrap-4 the parallax effect is not working. Is it expected behavior?

Can anyone please guide me on how to have the parallax effect when using the script?

Any help will be appreciated!

The code I have done

```js
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        parallax();
    });

    function parallax() {
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(".hero").css("top", -(scrolled * 0.0315) + "rem");
    }
```

```css
   .hero {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: bisque;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 80vh;
        background: #2c7b99;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="hero">
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="content">
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```